# How to Disable WebDAV Redirector server feature

Tags: windows-server-2019

I have Windows Server 2019 and installed SharePoint 2019 in it for enable Open with Explorer view in Server i enabled feature WebDAV Redirecter, now after enable now i want disable this feature and what are recommmended steps to disable this server feature.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove "WebDAV Publishing" from IIS to be able to remove "WebDAV Redirector"

Comment: Hi WebDAV Publishing not enabled in this Server Features under IIS

Comment: @adilahmed did you manage to remove WebDAV Redirector? If so, how?

Comment: Hi  yes disable windows server feature